# Send Keys Not Sending Outside Office Applications

Tags: vba, excel, outlook, sendkeys

So the project I'm working, I have a VBS script that I automatically run daily using Windows Task Scheduler. The VBS script calls this macro. However, my email in Outlook always has a pop up that I can't get rid of (not an option in my org.). I also can't call the "Send" key object on the pop up because the objects are in an access restricted directory. So I'm trying to use send keys to simply send the enter key to hit the pop up.

My problem is that my code for sendkeys only partly works. It sends the enter key, but it only sends the enter key when I'm in an MS Office application, but it won't send to the pop up. Any ideas?

```
Sub Mail_ActiveSheet()

' Refreshes webquery
Application.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
' Enters Title Comments in Cell M2
Range("$M$2").Value = "Comments"
' Enters formula in column M
Range("$M$3").Formula = Range("G3") & (",") & Range("L3")

' Draws formula to the end of the workbook
Dim Lastrow As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Lastrow = Range("L" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("M3:M" & Lastrow).Formula = "=G3&"",""&L3"
ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True



' Works in Excel 2000, Excel 2002, Excel 2003, Excel 2007, Excel 2010, Outlook 2000, Outlook 2002, Outlook 2003, Outlook 2007, Outlook 2010
    Dim FileExtStr As String
    Dim FileFormatNum As Long
    Dim Sourcewb As Workbook
    Dim Destwb As Workbook
    Dim TempFilePath As String
    Dim TempFileName As String
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim WshShell As Object


    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    Set Sourcewb = ActiveWorkbook

    ' Next, copy the sheet to a new workbook.
    ' You can also use the following line, instead of using the ActiveSheet object,
   ' if you know the name of the sheet you want to mail :
    ' Sheets("Sheet5").Copy
    ActiveSheet.Copy
    Set Destwb = ActiveWorkbook

    ' Determine the Excel version, and file extension and format.
    With Destwb
     Select Case Sourcewb.FileFormat
        Case 51: FileExtStr = ".csv": FileFormatNum = 6
        Case 52:
            If .HasVBProject Then
             FileExtStr = ".csv": FileFormatNum = 6
            Else
            FileExtStr = ".csv": FileFormatNum = 6
      End If
    Case 56: FileExtStr = ".csv": FileFormatNum = 6
    Case Else: FileExtStr = ".csv": FileFormatNum = 6
    End Select

    End With

    ' You can use the following statements to change all cells in the
   ' worksheet to values.
    '    With Destwb.Sheets(1).UsedRange
    '        .Cells.Copy
    '        .Cells.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    '        .Cells(1).Select
    '    End With
    '    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    ' Save the new workbook, mail, and then delete it.
    TempFilePath = Environ$("temp") & "\"
    TempFileName = "Part of " & Sourcewb.Name & " " _
                 & Format(Now, "dd-mmm-yy h-mm-ss")

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    With Destwb
        .SaveAs TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr, _
                FileFormat:=FileFormatNum
        On Error Resume Next
       ' Change the mail address and subject in the macro before
       ' running the procedure.
        With OutMail
            .To = "myemail@gmail.com"
            .CC = ""
            .BCC = ""
            .Subject = "Daily File"
            .Body = "Daily File"
            .Attachments.Add Destwb.FullName
            ' You can add other files by uncommenting the following statement.
            '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
            ' In place of the following statement, you can use ".Display" to
            ' display the mail.
            .Send
        End With
        On Error GoTo 0
        .Close SaveChanges:=False
    End With

    ' Delete the file after sending.
    Kill TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With

    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:04"))
    ActiveWindow.Activate
    Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    WshShell.SendKeys "~", True
    WshShell.SendKeys ("{NUMLOCK}")

End Sub
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I send clicks or keys from a VB6 app to an Excel dialog box?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/978557/how-can-i-send-clicks-or-keys-from-a-vb6-app-to-an-excel-dialog-box)

Comment: Use `FINDWINDOW` and `SENDMESSAGE` APIs in lieu of `SendKeys`

Comment: You probably need to do a `DoEvents` command after the sendkeys so the receiving window can process the message. _Yields execution so that the operating system can process other events._

**Syntax** `

DoEvents( )`

Comment: If you want to send the keys to the Outlook application then don't activate window in the Excel application - remove the `ActiveWindow.Activate`

Comment: I was able to get my script to work by putting the send keys command in a VBScript and then running both of the macros/scripts from a single batch (.bat) file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to remove the last block of code from my VBA macro and to create a VBScript to enter the send keys. In the end I have 2 VBScripts (one that calls my MACRO to run, then a second that runs my send key command). These VBScripts are both called from a batch (.bat) file.

This is the code I removed:

```
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:04"))
ActiveWindow.Activate
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.SendKeys "~", True
WshShell.SendKeys ("{NUMLOCK}")
```

Then this is what was placed in the sendkeys.vbs VBSCRIPT:

```
Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WScript.Sleep 9000
 oShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
```

Then this is my macro.vbs VBScript:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
curDir = fso.GetAbsolutePathName(".")

Set myxlApplication = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
myxlApplication.Visible = False
Set myWorkBook = myxlApplication.Workbooks.Open( "C:\Users\username\Desktop\macro.xlsm" ) 'Change to the actual workbook that has the Macro
myWorkBook.Application.Run "Module1.Mail_ActiveSheet" 'Change to the Module and Macro that contains your macro
myxlApplication.Quit
```

Then I just call both of those VBScripts from a batch file:

```
START C:\Users\username\Desktop\macro.vbs
START C:\Users\username\Desktop\sendkeys.vbs
```

Then all I have to do is run the batch file and it works like a charm.

Thanks for the suggestions!